# Powershell to check if a specific url is opened by any browsers

Tags: powershell

I would like the script to check if any of the opened browsers(checking, firefox, chrome, ie and edge) has a URL opened what contains (eg.: https://stackoverflow.com/). and if yes it would take the browser name (i.e.: firefox, chrome, edge, ie) and assign the exact URL to a variable.

Here this can check the browsers one by one

```
if (Get-Process iexplore) { "Internet Explorer is running" } else { "Internet Explorer is not running" }
if (Get-Process MicrosoftEdge) { "Microsft Edge is running" } else { "Microsft Edge is not running" }
if (Get-Process chrome) { "Google Chrome is running" } else { "Google Chrome is not running" }
if (Get-Process firefox) { "Firefox is running" } else { "Firefox is not running" }
```

so I would like to check if any of these 4 browsers are opened and if yes, on which ones a specific website is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Exact URL is not possible but you can check what host is used by which browser:

```
$server = 'stackoverflow.com'


$connections = Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object LocalAddress, LocalPort, @{Label="RemoteHost";Expression={ $h=(Resolve-DNSName $_.RemoteAddress).NameHost; if ($h) {$h} else {$_.RemoteAddress}}}, RemotePort, State, AppliedSetting, OwningProcess |
                ? { $_.RemoteHost -eq $server }

foreach( $connection in $connections ) {

    $process = get-process -Id ($connection.OwningProcess)
    $browser = $process.ProcessName

    "Host $($server) opened by $($browser)"

}
```

Comment: as a result, it shows me the URL as the server variable is assigned to it, however, the browser stays empty and does not display.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this only works if not utilizing a proxy.  When using a proxy, only sites set to bypass will show (usually internal corp, etc.)